# Web API using the ODATA Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We created a Web API which takes a Array of ID as input parameters and queries the Oracle Database, returns the result in JSON format. If the data returned is very large it throws an OutOfMemoryException issue. So planning to add an additional query parameter, which set of columns to return data.

Instead of loading loading the entire result set in to memory currently we are before serializing it out to the HttpResponseMessage. Our query is complex and huge, which selects 45 columns.I am just giving only few of the columns here as an example in the below code,

```
 using PSData.Models;
 namespace PSData.Controllers
 public class PDataController : ApiController
 {
 public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails([FromUri] string[] id)
 {
List<OracleParameter> prms = new List<OracleParameter>();
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PDataConnection"].ConnectionString;
using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
{
    DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
    var strQuery = @"SELECT STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.DESCR AS CATEGORY, 
                           STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.SESSION_NUM AS SESSION_NUMBER, 
                           Trunc(STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.START_DATE) AS SESSION_START_DATE, 
                           STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.START_DATE AS SESSION_START_TIME , 
                           Trunc(STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.END_DATE) AS SESSION_END_DATE, 
                           STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.END_DATE AS SESSION_END_TIME,
                           Round((TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.END_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'),'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') - TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.START_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'),'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'))*1440)AS SESSION_DURATION_MINUTES
                           from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY 
                           where STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.STD_REF IN(";
            var sb = new StringBuilder(strQuery);
            for (int x = 0; x < inconditions.Length; x++)
            {
                sb.Append(":p" + x + ",");
                var p = new OracleParameter(":p" + x, OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
                p.Value = inconditions[x];
                prms.Add(p);
            }
            if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Length--;
            strQuery = sb.Append(")").ToString();

            var returnObject = new { data = new OracleDataTableJsonResponse(connStr, strQuery, prms.ToArray()) };
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
            ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
            if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=PSData.json", out contentDisposition))
            {
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Now the api call is like

```
http://localhost:430/api/PData?id=JW21&id=BL02&id=AB02
```

I understand that there are these keywords `top` and `skip` in ODATA using IQueryable so the API call is

```
http://localhost:9658/api/values?$top=2&$skip=2
```

I am not sure how to implement the above in my approach, I created the Model class like below

```
namespace PSData.Models
{
public class StudyDataModel
{
    [Key]
    public string CATEGORY { get; set; }
    public int SESSION_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public DateTime SESSION_START_DATE { get; set; }
    public DateTime SESSION_START_TIME { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> SESSION_END_DATE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> SESSION_END_TIME { get; set; }
    public string DOSE_ACTIVITY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> SESSION_DURATION_MINUTES { get; set; }
 }
}
```

And

```
namespace PSData.Models
{
  public class StudyDataContext:DbContext
   {
    public DbSet<StudyDataModel> details { get; set; }
   }
}
```

But I am not sure how to implement them in my actual controller. Any help with this greatly appreciated.